# Does killing monster's nests reduce the number of monsters?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GemCraft#GemCraft_Labyrinth):

> Gem towers can now attack monster
>   lairs and beakons to destroy them.
>   note that monsters will always come in
>   from the edges of the map if their
>   nests are destroyed.

Does it mean that if I destroy a nest the same monsters that would have spawned at the nest would just spawn at one the edges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct sir. If you destroy the nest, the monsters will simply spawn from the edges, instead of the nest.

Comment: That's sad ... I was sure I was being really productive when I destroyed the nests.

Comment: @ripper234 - well, it does have an advantage if you've heavily tower'd the main path but have very few defenses along the monster lair route.

Comment: There's also battle amulets for destroying all the nests in a map so you get more XP.